# Scale down animated GIF with PHP GD

Tags: php, gd, gif

Is it possible to scale down a animated GIF with PHP GD so that it's still animated? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'm answering this about after 2 years but in case of someone looks for the same question:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7353-PHP-Resize-animations-in-files-of-the-GIF-format.html

The class is resizing GIF animations with GD. First parses the frames, then resizes them, after that it compiles them again into single file without losing its delay times,disposal methods, color tables etc.

Try and if you find a bug or want to suggest some optimizations etc. you can use the class' forum or leave a comment on the page in my website. And I'll answer that ASAP.

Comment: Useful but if the answer could be provided instead of providing a script that would be better.